# Function giving wrong output in Python

Tags: python

Through this code, i wish to replace all the dots (`.`) appearing in the string s with the character present at exactly the symmetrically opposite position. For eg: if `s=a.bcdcbba`, then the `.` should be replaced by `b`

**i.e:**

The element at `i`th position should be replaced by the element at `len(s)-i-1`th position. This function gives wrong output for the cases like `g....` , `.g...` etc. Any help ?

```
def replacedots(s):

  for i in range(0,len(s)):
      if s[i]==".":
              s=s.replace(s[i],s[len(s)-i-1],1)

  return s
```

Comment: what about `"foo.bar"`?

Comment: Do you mean the character after the dot?

Comment: It's because `s.replace` doesn't replace the dot at `i` but the first dot.

Comment: You need to add what you expect as output for the corner cases

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I don't see what's ambiguous. For `foo.bar`, the output should be `foo.bar`. The `.` is at index 3, and its "opposite" is the character at index 7-3-1=3, which is `.`, so the `.` is replaced with `.`, leaving the input unchanged.

Comment: @ChrisMartin, I am not the OP and don't know the requirements so that is where the ambiguity comes from, if they are supposed to use replace then I would like to see how that would work. *This function gives wrong output for the cases like g.... , .g... etc.* is not how to ask a question regardless

Comment: @PadraicCunningham The first two sentences clearly and unambiguously articulate a question. OP's attempt at a solution uses replace, but no one said "they are supposed to use replace".

Comment: @ChrisMartin,  again, I am not the OP and for that matter neither are you so why not let the OP reply. I also did not *make up* anything I wrote,  *if they are supposed to use replace*. Notice the *if*.

Comment: Thanks every one ! Especially @Dombi Szabolcs .

Answer (score 1):

@chepner's way:

```
def replacedots(s):
    return ''.join(x if x !='.' else y for x, y in zip(s, reversed(s)))
```

an alternative:

```
def replacedots(s):
    return ''.join(c if c != '.' else s[-i - 1] for i, c in enumerate(s))
```

When the char at position `i` and the char at position `len(s) - i - 1` is a `.` the dot will remain a dot.

**Example:**

```
s = "foo.bar"
```

Comment: Nice ! but isn't `s[-i - 1]` enought to get the opposite char ?

Comment: sure, thank you (next time feel free to edit an answer you can improve) :)

Comment: Some--me :)--might find it cleaner to use `x if x !='.' else y for x, y in zip(s, reversed(s))` and avoid direct indexing. Either way, it is faster to pass a list comprehension instead of a generator to `''.join`. (Oddly enough, the `zip` version is faster than the`enumerate` version when generators are used, but not when both are used as list comprehensions.)